# Detect rails 2 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to detect rack apps and rails 2 apps by simply inspecting the files in a project.

I've been able to do this for rack apps by checking for the existence of a config.ru file. Is there something similar I could check for in a rails 2 app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Phusion Passeger documentation](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#application_detection): Phusion Passenger checks whether the virtual host is a Rails application by checking whether the following file exists:

```
dirname(DocumentRoot) + "/config/environment.rb"
```

This file exists also for rails 3 projects if that is a problem :/.

Comment: If it's good enough for them it's good enough for me :) I'm checking for rack apps or any rails app so it matching rails 3 as well is fine.

Answer (score 1):

In `config/environment.rb` you can look for `RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.x.x'`

In Gemfile.lock for `rails (2.x.x)`

In Gemfile for `gem 'rails', '2.x.x'`

Answer (score 0):

The file `config/environment.rb` should have a statement which mentions the required version of rails, e.g.:

```
# Specifies gem version of Rails to use when vendor/rails is not present
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.5' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION
```